# Uninteresting BHO dll 64 bit and 32 bit using regsvr32 cause 0x8002801c error

Tags: dll, com, 32bit-64bit, atl, regsvr32

I have created simple BHO with ATL using these instructions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489(v=vs.85).aspx. I am creating both 64 bit and 32 bit dll of the dll. The problem happens when I try to to unregistered the 64 bit dll after the 32 bit version using regsvr32, I am getting 0x8002801c error.
(If I try vise versa the same problem happens). I have added images to celrify.

I think it has something to do with TypeLib registration because I it does the same thing for the 64 bit and 32 bit with no difference, after registering the 32 bit i have these two keys

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{5EA5008F-7766-499D-B4B0-9A671C752333}\1.0\0\win32 default = C:\programming\vswork\testfile\test64atlcom\Debug\test64atlcom.dll

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib{5EA5008F-7766-499D-B4B0-9A671C752333}\1.0\0\win32 default = C:\programming\vswork\testfile\test64atlcom\Debug\test64atlcom.dll

Why does this happens, and how can solve it?

[image: Registering]

[image: unregister]

Comment: The error code is `TYPE_E_REGISTRYACCESS` and I would look into making sure your x64 build has 64-bit target environment (Project Settings, MIDL; `/env`)

Comment: thanks a lot!!! it seems to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code is `TYPE_E_REGISTRYACCESS`. A typical problem with VS projects is that default template does not have `x64` configuration and it's copying from `Win32` does not update target environment in MIDL settings.

[image]

`x64` build with `Win32` would load and run, however it's registration would still COM-register the type library as 32-bit and cause 32/64-bit build collision.

So, you need to make sure that type libraries in `Win32` builds target 32-bit, and `x64` builds have them target 64-bit environment.